# Javascript group array of object by near dates

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, grouping

i can't understand how to group an array of object inside a timeline.

Let me explain,

the ***timeline*** is created from a range of dates, it reach +90 year from the start date.

```
const timeline = [
    {
        year: '2015',
        items: []
    },
    {
        year: '2016',
        items: []
    }
];
```

Inside the ***timeline.items*** i have to push other items coming from another array of objects, ***timelineItems***

```
const timelineItems = [
    {
        year: '2015',
        somedata:'somevalue'
    },
    {
        year: '2016',
        somedata:'somevalue'
    }
];
```

In some situations, i have to group those values, based on the diff from the ***timeline.year*** and the ***timlineItems.year***

This is the expected results

```
const timeline = [{
        year: '2015',
        items: [{
                year: '2015',
                somedata: 'somevalue'
            },
            {
                year: '2016',
                somedata: 'somevalue'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        year: '2016',
        items: []

    }
];
```

I am trying to map the timeline.items with a function who check the difference between the first year found and the next 3 years, but i'm having some problem.
I still don't understand how to do this.

I've made this https://jsfiddle.net/ghmtL8cf/ with the initial data and some comments to help understand the desired output.

***UPDATE***

Thanks to @Nur answer i was able to perform the first grouping.

[This is the link](https://jsfiddle.net/04ecd7v5/) of the updated jsfiddle with more input and a expected output.

In the expected output i would like to have the grouping applied only if the first timelineItems is equal to the actual timeline year.

Looking at the problem i would like to add another idea.

Should we split the timeline inside chunk of 3 and for each chunk add the timelineItems equal to the start-end of the chunk years?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think `{year: '2016',somedata: 'somevalue'}` should belong to year *2016* ?

Comment: Because of the logic of te near year, if the 2016 is in the group of the previous year i have to skip the insertion

Comment: um, I found it so confusion, can you give more detail... Also Provide more data in your `input`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a tricky problem. At first Check if `timelineItems` exist in `timelineRef`, if it doesn't then create a ref and push item into `timeline`, else find the `timeline` from `timelineRef` then push item and continue loop...

It should solve your problem, And this is super efficient!

```js
let timeline = [{ year: '2015', items: [] }, { year: '2016', items: [] }, { year: '2019', items: [] }, { year: '2023', items: [] }, { year: '2024', items: [] }, { year: '2025', items: [] }, { year: '2026', items: [] }],
    timelineItems = [{ year: '2015', somedata: 'somevalue' }, { year: '2016', somedata: 'somevalue' }, { year: '2019', somedata: 'somevalue' }, { year: '2023', somedata: 'somevalue' }, { year: '2024', somedata: 'somevalue' }, { year: '2025', somedata: 'somevalue' }];

function group(timeline, timelineItems) {
    const timelineRef = [];
    loop: for (const item of timelineItems) {
        for (const { year, items } of timelineRef)
            if (year < item.year && item.year < year + 3) {
                items.push(item);
                continue loop;
            }

        for (const { year, items } of timeline) {
            if (year != item.year) continue;
            items.push(item);
            timelineRef.push({ year: Number(year), items });
            break;
        }
    }
    return timeline;
}
console.log(group(timeline, timelineItems));
```

Comment: It would be nice if you provide more item in input and your expected output...

Comment: Hi, first of all thanks for trying to help me out understand the possible solutions, i have tried your solution but i still have a problem. 

I have update the jsfiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/2wtx0hgj/) and i have added another item in the timelineItems. 

The grouping need another rules, before the group function, i have to check if the year inside the timeline is equal to the year of the timelineItems and then add the other timelineItems within range.

In the jsfiddle the timelineItems with year 2019 is inside the timeline year 2016 instead of 2019.

Thanks

Comment: Nope, im facing the problem described up, i have the timelineItem year 2019 inside the timeline year 2016, instead of 2019.

Comment: I can't help with so less information... 1st why is should belong to  `2019` ? can you please updated your question with more input, with your desire output?